# imx6 GPIO interrupt status register (ISR) bad values

Tags: c++, interrupt, imx6

I am trying to use GPIO interrups by reading the ISR (interrupt status register) flags. Application note says that the reset value should be equal to 0 (reference manual at page:1433) but it's not (it's 0xCF08FEFF) while i'am reading this on startup. I am also trying to reset this value manually using: 
*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ISR_OFFSET)=0xFFFFFFFF;

where: gpio3_base address is mapped using mmap() ang its *volatile unsigned long type* and GPIO_ISR_OFFSET= 0x18/sizeof(long).

**But the value is still the same...** Other registers work properly. I don't know what can be wrong or if i missed something.

Also aplication note says that this register needs "One wait state for reset" but I don't know how can i do this "wait state" in C++/C (maybe this is the main problem)

I'm using imx6 quad with Debian. (kernel 3.14.60-fslc-imx6-sr armv7L)

Link to reference manual [i.mx6quad reference manual](http://www.nxp.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/IMX6DQRM.pdf?fasp=1&WT_TYPE=Reference%20Manuals&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf)

```
//SETTING UP INTERRUPT CONTROL REGISTER FOR GPIO_IO09 ICR1 I ICR2
cout<<"startup value ICR1="<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR1_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;
//setting up new value for GPIO_IO09 in ICR1
    *(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR1_OFFSET)&=0;
    *(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR1_OFFSET)|=0xC0000;// set FALLING EDGE for GPIO_IO09
    cout<<"new value in ICR1:"<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR1_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;

//ICR2 RESET  
cout<<"startup value ICR2:"<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR2_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;
if(*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR1_OFFSET)!=0){  //0 is default value
    *(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR1_OFFSET)&=0;
cout<<"new value ICR2:"<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ICR1_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;
}
//IMR
cout<<"startup value IMR:"<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_IMR_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;
*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_IMR_OFFSET)&=0;
*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_IMR_OFFSET)|=(1<<9);  //odblokowywanie przerwania od GPIO_IO09
cout<<"new value IMR:"<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_IMR_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;

//ISR reset  -- PROBLEM IS HERE 
cout<<"address:"<<((&gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ISR_OFFSET))<<endl;
cout<<"startup value ISR: "<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ISR_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;
*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ISR_OFFSET)=0xFFFFFFFF;   
cout<<"new value ISR :"<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_ISR_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;


//EDGE_SEL register reset
cout<<"startup value EDGE_SEL: "<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_EDGE_SEL_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;  // "h" == hex
*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_EDGE_SEL_OFFSET)&=0;
cout<<"new value EDGE_SEL: "<<std::hex<<*(gpio3_base_address+GPIO_EDGE_SEL_OFFSET)<<"h"<<endl;
```